# POSIX SHELL: Assigning expansion of glob to a variable

Tags: linux, shell, posix, shellcheck

Been searching for solutions to this problem, but haven't found any good ones. Just about every answer assumes Bash and uses arrays, which is not what I want.

So, I have this path, which may have slight variations to it, which I'd like to assign to a variable like so:

```bash
debs="${builds}/${name}/${version}"_*.deb
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as intended, the glob is not expanded in the assignment, see [SC2125](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2125).

Another thing I tried was to assign with parameter expansion, i.e.

```bash
unset debs
: ${debs:="${builds}/${name}/${version}"_*.deb}
```

This too, doesn't seem to expand the glob the way it's supposed to.

Now, arrays are not an option, so I'm not sure what else there is. One way to do it should be to just expand and echo it, e.g.

```bash
debs=$(echo "${builds}/${name}/${version}"_*.deb)
```

which seems to solve the problem, but doesn't exactly feel "correct". Is there any better, more idiomatic way to go about this without shelling out to echo, or is this as good as it gets when hanging onto ancient shells?

Comment: Assigning the result of a glob to a variable is probably incorrect on its own, for precisely the same reasons that arrays have been introduced by other shells: the assignment loses the distinction between literal spaces and delimiter spaces.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to *do* with the variable once you have the result? If you are going to expand it without quotes, you may as well just assign the glob itself to the variable and let the unquoted expansion do the blobbing. (There might be some differences between the two approaches in corner cases; I haven't thought this out thoroughly.)

Comment: @chepner

The idea here is I have one or more files I want to loop over and do something with, either entered through the command line, or by finding it with a glob in a default location, if there's no files passed as arguments. The reason I use a glob here is because a Debian package may end in e.g. `_all`, `_amd64`, etc. Which particular one doesn't matter, but there should only be the one per package on the system.

However, you're right that it's probably easier to just store the glob and expand it later, given that I dispatch it by looping over the var anyway, in this case only one.

Comment: @chepner Another use case I had, which is probably more reasonable is wanting to gather all files matching a pattern to then pass to `rsync` later. Granted, I can also expand the glob on use there. Shellcheck dislikes this, so maybe it's a footgun, but it also does seem to do what it's supposed to. I guess the answer is to just not save the expanded glob, but instead store it, and expand on use.

Comment: POSIX sh only has one array, `"$@"` (well, one per stack frame, since each function gets its own). If there's nothing in it you need you can override it in place (as with `set -- "$builds/$name/$version"_*.deb`), but very much the better answer is "don't".

Comment: ...as chepner said above, the `debs=$(echo ..._*.deb)` approach is buggy -- it can't distinguish between a space in a filename and a space intended to separate filenames.

Comment: I agree. I think the least bad solution here is to simply store the glob and expand on usage.